# How to get specific field value from response object after certain search query and apply loop on the returned items

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, node-modules

I have written a script in Node.js which has to identify the other required version of document (duplicated one), and then remove the version by replacing it.

For example

Document 1 `d_path`:

```
file://storage004.directory.intra/abc.txt
```

Document 2 `d_path`:

```
file://homestore.directory.intra/abc.txt,
```

So basically these two documents are both similar except for the word `homestore` and `storage004`, so basically DUPLICATE, and we have approximately 25 million data to process, so our requirement is to delete the `storage004` version of all duplicated documents.

Trouble/Issue: I'm new to node.js, and I want to extract a field from `_source`, (field name is `d_path`), and apply loop conditions over there, below as of now for loop is commented out,

Problem is how to return/extract a `d_path` value from `result.hits.hits`

```
async function index(req, res, next) {

    let esFinalQuery = {
        "query": {
            "match_phrase": {
                "d_path": "file://story.directory.intra/"
            }
        },
    };

    //return res.send(esFinalQuery);

    const result = await esClient.search({
        index: 'elasticduplicate',
        type: '_doc',
        body: esFinalQuery
    })
    .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);
    });

    var homeArr=[];
    //homeArr=result.hits.hits;
    /*for (item in homeArr) {
        const path_of_duplicate = item._source.d_path.replace('homestore', 'storage004')
        const document = esClient.exists({
            index: 'elasticduplicate',
            type: '_doc',
            body: {
                query: {
                    match: {
                        "d_path.keyword":path_of_duplicate
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        if (document) {
            await esClient.deleteByQuery({
                index: "elasticduplicate",
                type: "_doc",
                body: {
                    query: {
                        match: { "d_path.keyword": path_of_duplicate }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }*/
    return res.send(result.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
        homeArr.push('yeah '+hit);
    }));
    
}
```

Comment: In order to help you, you should share the data structure of `result.hits.hits`. 

Beside of this, I see a problem on the last return: you are sending undefined, as forEach returns always undefined... I guess you need array.prototype.map there.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps:

```js
async function index(req, res, next) {
  const docsToKeep = await esClient.search({
    index: "elasticduplicate",
    type: "_doc",
    body: {
      query: {
        match_phrase: {
          d_path: "file://story.directory.intra/",
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const foundDuplicates = [];

  for (const docToKeep of docsToKeep.hits.hits) {
    const pathOfDuplicate = docToKeep._source.d_path.replace(
      "homestore",
      "storage004"
    );

    const duplicateExists = await esClient.exists({
      index: "elasticduplicate",
      type: "_doc",
      body: {
        query: {
          match: {
            "d_path.keyword": pathOfDuplicate,
          },
        },
      },
    });

    if (duplicateExists) {
      await esClient.deleteByQuery({
        index: "elasticduplicate",
        type: "_doc",
        body: {
          query: {
            match: { "d_path.keyword": pathOfDuplicate },
          },
        },
      });

      foundDuplicates.push(pathOfDuplicate);
    }
  }

  res.send(JSON.stringify(foundDuplicates));
}
```

Notes:

- Make sure the original match query `d_path:"file://story.directory.intra/"` is correct
- Remember to `await` all asynchronous (ES/network) calls
- Looks like you're planning to run this inside of a web server (express?) handler. Considering there's a lot of records to process it may time out stopping mid-way (you can still re-run and continue from where you left but you won't get your end of script stats).